# No Scaffold widget found : Getting exception while opening Bottom Dialog sheet

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I'm using Scaffold widget but while opening a bottom dialog sheet I'm getting this exception

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Calendar"),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
  .......
  .......

    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          //getting exception here
                          showBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ));
                        },
```

I'm stuck on this code, it'll be very helpful if someone can give any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: add your whole code

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that the `context` used to show the `BottomSheet` is not the `context` of the `Scaffold`. You can solve this issue by using `GlobalKey` or wrap your `GestureDetector` in a `Builder` widget so that it gives you the `context` that contains a reference of the `Scaffold`.

Here is a example using `GlobalKey` with the state of the `Scaffold`:

```
// created the ScaffoldState key    
final scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      void _showSheet() {
        // Show BottomSheet here using the Scaffold state instead of the Scaffold context
        scaffoldState.currentState
            .showBottomSheet((context) => Container(color: Colors.red));
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldState,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Calendar"),
            ),
            body: SafeArea(child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
              //getting exception here
              _showSheet();
            })));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I ran in to different error, while using your code

The method 'addLocalHistoryEntry' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: addLocalHistoryEntry(Instance of 'LocalHistoryEntry')

Comment: Wich class are you using to call addLocalHistoryEntry?

Comment: This what what I needed - I wanted to offset the bottom sheet by the navigationbar and not have it "scroll in" over the top of that and showModalBottomSheet did not allow seem to allow that even with inset.

Answer (score 50):

Use `showModalBottomSheet` instead of `showBottomSheet` try out **below** eg.

```
void _settingModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return Container(
        child: new Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.music_note),
                title: new Text('Music'),
                onTap: () => {}
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.videocam),
              title: new Text('Video'),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: why it works??... what is the difference.

Comment: Why this works is because `showModalBottomSheet` looks up for nearest `Navigator` and `Theme`...unlike `showBottomSheet` which looks for nearest `Scaffold`... 

i.e. to use `showBottomDialog` you should use context from a Scaffold like what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072540/10603758)

Comment: While this is working, be aware you will indeed open a Modal which is different from a classic BottomSheet and as different behavior (look at the accepted answer if you don't want a Modal).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the widget tree with Builder widget

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Calendar"),
  ),
  body: Builder(  //HERE
     builder:(context){
    
     return SafeArea(
     .......
     .......

    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          //getting exception here
                          showBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ));
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% aware of why this works but I am guessing because its outside of the scaffold.

```
 class Example extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            
            appBar: AppBar(
              
            ),
            body: SafeArea(child: YourWidget(),
)
);
      }
    }

class YourWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          //getting exception here
                          showBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ));
}
   );
  }
}
```